# Pictures are very small when added to UIimageview in Interface Builder

Tags: iphone, uiimageview

I have 6 images, all the same size (65x65). When I create an imageview and add this image through the "image view attributes" in the interface builder, the picture is very small. Maybe 5x5. The pictures also show up small when viewing them in the resource folder however, when running the program, they are the right size. Is there some setting I need to change to get the images to show the full size/full resolution within the interface builder?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Make sure your UIImageView is active, then go to Layout -> Size to Fit (Command + '=' should also do the trick). This way the UIImageView will resize to fit the image and it'll look nice when looking at your stuff in IB.

Answer (score 0):

Adjust the resolution of your image files to 72 dpi.