# Is there a shortcut key to fit UIImageView's dimension to a .png?

Tags: iphone, xcode, interface-builder

After adding a UIImageView to Interface Builder and assigning a png filename to it, is there a shortcut key to use the PNG's dimension (width and height) as the UIImageView's dimension?

Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Size to Fit command, shortcut is Command + '='

Similar to this question: [Pictures are very small when added to UIimageview in Interface Builder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/955849/pictures-are-very-small-when-added-to-uiimageview-in-interface-builder)